# How to change description of Standard Object

Tags: sobject, standard-objects, admin, setup

Does anyone know if there is a way to edit the description of a standard object, I have an Edit button only on Custom object.

[image]

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can update the Description of standard objects by using Metadata API and a package ZIP file. You'll need to specify the `<description>` attribute in the object file.

For example, to update the Description of the Account object, use this folder structure:

- unmanaged.zip

  - package.xml
  - objects

    - Account.object

package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Account</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>55.0</version>
</Package>
```

Account.object

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <description>Represents an individual account, which is an organization or person involved with your business (such as customers, competitors, and partners).</description>
</CustomObject>
```

I personally use Workbench to access Metadata API. You can refer to this help article for details on how to use it: [Use Metadata API to retrieve and deploy using Workbench](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=How-to-use-Metadata-API-to-retrieve-and-deploy-contents)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an way to update the **Description** details of the Std object. Based on the [SFDC Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm) you can only able to update the Standard field `Description` not object `properties`.

[image]

Thanks.